# IN clause to select all elements if list is empty/null

Tags: java, jpa

I have the follow @Query in my repository :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tableA a WHERE a.id IN :listId ",
    nativeQuery = true)
public Page<ObjectA> findInById(@Param(listId) List<String> listId);
```

And I would like to select all elements if `listId` is empty or null.

How can I do that? If possible I'd like to keep the `@Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an or condition, like

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tableA a 
    WHERE (a.id IN :listId or coalesce(:listId , null)  is null)",
    nativeQuery = true)
public Page<ObjectA> findInById(@Param(listId) List<String> listId);
```

Comment: It's ginving me an error : ```org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error on or near « $2 »```. When the list isn't empty/null it works fine.

Comment: I've updated the answer to try to resolve the case where :listId is null/empty, hope it helps